# C2664 :when I use str.append(str[i]),error happening

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

```
    string s1;
    string s2;
    getline(cin >> fixed, s);
    for (int j = 0; j < s.length(); j++)
    {
        if ((j & 1) == 0)
        {
            s1.append(s[j]);//the type of s[j] is char,but the error still 
                            //happening,
            cout << tmp << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            s2.append(s[j]);
        }
    }
    cout << s1 << " " << s2 << endl;
```

C2664“std::basic_string,std::allocator> &std::basic_string,std::allocator>::append(const std::basic_string,std::allocator> &)”: can't convert elem 1 form “char” to “std::initializer_list<_Elem>”

Comment: as the error says...you try to pass a `char type` to a `string type`

Comment: You're right: the type of `s[j]` _is_ a `char`, but the error says that `append` doesn't want a `char`

Comment: If you look at some [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/append) you'll notice that `append` is for appending other strings or multiple characters, not single ones. Use `+=`.

Comment: Please don't edit the compiler's error messages. Just paste them directly into the question, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is no overload of `append()` that takes a single `char`. Have a look here:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/append

Only one overload takes a single `char`:

```
basic_string& append( size_type count, CharT ch );
```

So, you could use this:

```
 s1.append(1, s[j]);
```

Alternatively, use `operator+=` instead:

```
s1 += s[j];
```